Oracle's row_number() paging efficiency is low in hibernate6
In Hibernate 6, Oracle used row_number() for paging, but I found that its efficiency is not as good as rownum when the data is large. The field 'order by' has been indexed.
200w data takes approximately 11 seconds to process.Is there any way to make Hibernate use rownum for paging.
This is my code.
 BlazeJPAQuery<SyncMapTaskResponse> blazeJPAQuery = new BlazeJPAQuery<>(entityManager, criteriaBuilderFactory)
            .select(Projections.fields(SyncMapTaskResponse.class,
                    mapTask.mapTaskId,
                    mapTask.mapId,
                    mapTask.beginTime,
                    mapTask.endTime,
                    mapTask.dataCount,
                    mapTask.status,
                    mapTask.ip,
                    mapTask.insertTime,
                    mapTask.updateTime))
            .from(mapTask)
            .where(builder)
            .orderBy(QSyncMapTask.syncMapTask.beginTime.desc());

        Pageable pageable = paginationRequest.pageable();
        long total = blazeJPAQuery.fetchCount();
        List<SyncMapTaskResponse> list = blazeJPAQuery.offset(pageable.getOffset())
            .limit(pageable.getPageSize())
            .fetch();

This is the SQL generated by Hibernate.
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT smt1_0.map_task_id                                             AS c0
           , smt1_0.map_id                                                  AS c1
           , smt1_0.begin_time                                              AS c2
           , smt1_0.end_time                                                AS c3
           , smt1_0.data_count                                              AS c4
           , smt1_0.status                                                  AS c5
           , smt1_0.ip                                                      AS c6
           , smt1_0.insert_time                                             AS c7
           , smt1_0.update_time                                             AS c8
           , row_number() OVER (ORDER BY smt1_0.begin_time DESC NULLS LAST) AS rn
      FROM t_sync_map_task smt1_0) r_0_
WHERE r_0_.rn <= 50
  AND r_0_.rn > 1
ORDER BY r_0_.rn;


Perhaps you could post your code and list the actions you have tried, as well as the SQL generated by Hibernate?

added  generated  sql

Two things to note. First in terms of performance, you want to see
WINDOW SORT PUSHED RANK
or
SORT ORDER BY STOPKEY
in your execution plan. That indicates that Oracle has detected you are doing a "top-n" style query as opposed to a conventional sort.
Secondly, effectively that is an "offset" style approach, ie,

page 1 = get 'n' rows
page 2 = get '2n' rows and throw away the first 'n'
page 3 = get '3n' rows and throw away the first '2n'

etc. That is (a) expensive and (b) generally doesn't work, because the table data typically changes as you navigate through the result set. For example, if your page size was 5 rows, and every time you hit page down, someone else had inserted 5 new rows, there's a chance your "scrolling" would show the same rows every time.
For more details, a couple of videos

for the performance

https://youtu.be/rhOVF82KY7E

for a better pagination approach

https://youtu.be/0TdqGlA4bxI
